# Google Charts: Why am I getting two select events when I have animation turned on

Tags: google-visualization

I attach a select event to charts -- a column chart and a pie chart

When I turn on animation, I get *two* select events for a single column select action from the column chart (but just one, correctly, from the pie chart, which doesn't animate).

For the column chart, the first event returns the correct selection data `[{column:1, row:1}]`, but the second event returns an empty array.

With animation turned off (commented out) I get the correct response, namely only one event when a user selects a column.

Has anyone seen this? What do I do? I haven't found any value that lets me even differentiate whether the event is occurring in the presence of animation, or any other logical way to at least filter out the rogue second event. Obviously I would like to suppress the incorrect second event when animation is turned on.

Here's the animation spec:

```
let options = {
    animation:{
        startup: true,
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'out',
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

the `'select'` event on a ColumnChart seems to be working fine with animation here,
see following working snippet...

is there more you can share?
are you creating the charts directly or using the ChartWrapper class?
which packages are you using, `'corechart'`?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Energy Level');
    data.addRows([
      [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1, .25],
      [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2, .5],
      [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3, 1],
      [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4, 2.25],
      [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5, 2.25],
      [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6, 3],
      [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7, 4],
      [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8, 5.25],
      [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9, 7.5],
      [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10, 10],
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([{sourceColumn:0, type: 'string', calc: 'stringify'}, 1]);

    var options = {
      animation:{
        startup: true,
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'out',
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Time of Day',
        format: 'h:mm a',
        viewWindow: {
          min: [7, 30, 0],
          max: [17, 30, 0]
        }
      },
      isStacked: true,
      title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)'
      }
    };

    var chartCol = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('column_div'));
    var chartPie = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartCol, 'select', function () {
     showSelection(chartCol);
    });
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartPie, 'select', function () {
     showSelection(chartPie);
    });
    
    function showSelection(sender) {
      document.getElementById('msg_div').innerHTML += (new Date()).getTime() + ' -- ' + JSON.stringify(sender.getSelection()) + '<br/>';    
    }

    chartCol.draw(data, options);
    chartPie.draw(view, {
     legend: 'none',
      theme: 'maximized'
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="column_div"></div>
<div id="pie_div"></div>
<div id="msg_div"></div>
```

Comment: There were two issues it seems, stemming from my need to have the selection outline appear on a number of side-by-side (drill-down) charts. Selection seems to be cleared when a chart loses focus. So I have to restore it with setSelection. This can seemingly cause 'select' event to be triggered a second time in the presence of animation. Secondly, the selection is cleared after animation is finished. I finally purged all setSelections except as triggered by 'animationtrigger' event. Works now. Using npm react-google-charts. See dev.budgetpedia.ca/explorer

Comment: that should be 'animationfinish' not 'animationtrigger'

Comment: I'll investigate why selection is cleared in the first place; something to do with react event environment I've created, I presume. React re-renders things quite a lot; maybe that's it.

Comment: not sure i follow, but clicking once selects the column, clicking the same column again de-selects it -- this triggers the event, even though there is no selection. i've never seen a chart _lose selection_ any other way...

Comment: Did some testing. React has a one-way data flow pattern, which causes render() to be invoked in response to most state changes. The react google chart library I use generates a wrapper.draw() whenever one of these cycles is invoked. This seems to be what causes de-selection, as a side effect. Still investigating details. Currently I'm compensating by generating a setSelection on animationfinish, which happens after event cycles have died down. I may just have to live with it for now.